# Stuck at beginning in Android Studio. Blank Design Screen. No Hello World

Tags: android-studio

Hello I am a beginner and when I launch Studio, I get a blank Design screen, instead of Hello World. No matter how many textviews or buttons I add, blank design screen. Please help!

Default Code on Launch:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably because you created more activities and those are showing before it. In your Android Manifest, in the part where activities are declared, you should specify yours as the Main Activity and as the launcher. Like so:

```
        <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/MainActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        .
        .
        .
        <!-- intent filter makes this activity the initial -->
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Comment: Thank you, I tried to change it, and no luck. I uninstalled the Studio program, deleted all files, and started from scratch (twice). When a new project initially loads, I get a blank blueprint every time, even before I make any changes whatsoever.. No name of the app in design view, no colored app bar as shown in examples. Ugh! Thank you for your input, now I learned more about manifests lol! :)

Comment: Hmm maybe in Android Studio->build-> clean project and rebuild options, other than that and reinstalling while removing all files (they are located in more than one folder) ai cant think of anything more